# Firestore Data Structuring: Storing An Order in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store an "order" in Firestore. It's basically several rows of part#, description, quantity, and price. My initial thought is to store each order as a document where each line/row/lineItem is an array.

Considering search/scale, is this recommended? Or, should each line item of the "order" be a separate document of a top-level collection("order1")?

```
PART1A    a desc of part1a    3    13.95
PART2B    aanother descrip    7    9.99
```

UPDATE: *Below is my solution. I spent (wasted) a long time thinking about how to `.then` update my db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("orders"). After an hour I understood there no reason to do this at all. I've captured the uid in the `db.collection("orders").doc()` already and can quickly query that to pull a users orders up.*

```
    ordersPageSaveButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        var batch = db.batch();
        var ordersRef = db.collection("orders").doc();
        var itemRows = parentEl.querySelectorAll(".selected-item-row");
        var name;
        var description;
        var quantity;
        var price;
        var indx;
        var obj = {};
        //order name would be nice
        obj.updated = Date.now();
        obj.owner = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        obj.stage = "saved";
        for (var i = 0; i < itemRows.length; i++) {
            name = itemRows[i].querySelector(".product-container-item-name-wrapper").innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase();
            description = itemRows[i].querySelector(".product-container-description-row").innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase();
            quantity = Number(itemRows[i].querySelector(".product-container-qty-input").value);
            price = itemRows[i].querySelector(".product-container-unit-price-wrapper").innerHTML;
            price = parseFloat(price.replace(/,/g, ''));
            indx = itemRows[i].querySelector(".product-container-row-number-wrapper").innerHTML;
            obj[name] = {
            indx:indx,
            description:description,
            quantity:quantity,
            price:price};
            batch.set(ordersRef, obj);
        }
        // Commit the batch
        batch.commit().then(function () {
            console.log("success");
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: As is the general case for nosql databases, it depends entirely on how you intend to query your data.  Without knowing your required queries, it's not really possible to say what's the best structure.

Comment: I would like user to be able to search for all orders including "red" in the description.  [Firestore Query Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) is my concern there.

Comment: There's no full text searching in Firestore.  You'll need to copy your data to another database for that.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: I think a map (object notation instead of [ ] notation) does support querying -> [Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays). Maybe this is the answer I'm looking for if anyone wants the points...

Comment: Sure, if you want to put every single word into that map, then assume that the word you're looking for hasn't been pluralized, changed tense, converted to an adjective or adverb, abbreviated, etc.

Comment: Right, OK I see. I figure then the best I could do is store the description, quantity, and price as children of part#. Full Text Search is what I was after and got it, [supported via 3rd party only per Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search). ...k Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the firtly mentioned structure is the way to go. Use the order name as the key (`collection/$ordername`) and description, quantity and price as values.

```
PART1A
    description: "This is desc of part1a"
    quantity: 3
    price: 13.95
```

This way you can order by any of the values and the name.

Comment: I'm thinking of a future senario where user wants to search all their orders for PART1A. ...right, I guess that would work. I can't think of why anyone would search on quantity, or price which was my concern, namely how to query the "orders". However description... They want to search based on item description. [Firestore Query Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) is my concern there.

Comment: If you want to search across all order for those with a line item for PART1A, you can't put the line items in a subcollection of each order since you can't currently search across subcollections. That means you should either keep the line items of all orders in a single top-level collection (similar to how you might do this on the Firebase Realtime Database), or go with a different structure alltogether where you keep a document for PART1A that then has a reference to all orders in which the part is present.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ty, ok got it. I don't want to nail the PART1A down as it's description or price might change over time and then back-pollute my historical / completed orders. ...if my mind is thinking right.